# Re-setting iTerm on MacOS X

Tags: macos, mac

I somehow screw up my iTerm configuration. Now I click the iTerm icon, it shows the menu bar and icon on the dock, but it won't pop up any windows.

So I did:

- remove it from `/Application` and reinstall it,
- remove the `~/Library/Application Support/iTerm`,

but that does not solve my problem.

Any other ideas please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a quote from the iTerm page:

> **Where does iTerm store its settings?**
>
> Since version 0.8.0, all the setting is stored in ~/Library/Preferences/iTerm.plist. In case something goes wrong, you can delete this file and iTerm will generate a new settings file that should always work.

Quit iTerm before you delete the preferences file and when you restart, it should be OK.

http://iterm.sourceforge.net/faq.shtml

Answer (score 38):

None of the other solutions worked for me. This is from the [new FAQ page](http://iterm2.com/faq.html):

```
defaults delete com.googlecode.iterm2
```

Comment: To delete run: `rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist`

Answer (score 7):

iterm2 settings are stored in `~/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist`.  Removing that file will allow the program to reset to the defaults.

Answer (score 2):

I had some problems (it was hanging on a paste of one normal character), and the following `rm` solved it for me.

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/iTerm/
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a preferences file that also needs to be deleted, from the following directory:

```
~/Library/Preferences/
```

Not sure what it is called for iTerm, but it is likely to be something like:

```
com.company.iTerm.plist
```

Don't delete the whole directory, though!

Comment: BE CAREFUL don't delete the entire directory.  To find the other files you need to delete, use an uninstaller like AppZapper.

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't make that clear!